# Python binary to multi- hex

Tags: python, format, hex, bin, ord

I am trying to read a file in binary and return for example "ffffff" a series of 6 hex codes. does this make sense? The code I have (below) only returns a list of 2 so it looks like "ff"

```
fp = open(f, 'rb')
hex_list = ("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in fp.read())
```

i am specifically looking to make this return something like

```
['ab0012', 'ffbaf0']
```

not like

```
['ab', '00', '12', 'ff', 'ba', 'f0']
```

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you considered reading 3 bytes at a time?

Comment: Can you put an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
fp = open(f, 'rb')
hex_list = ["{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in fp.read()]
return [''.join(hex_list[n:n+3]) for n in range(0, len(hex_list), 3)]
```

Comment: aha I like the way you think Thanks. if you find a more direct way to do it though please let me know  thanks again